# Guess A Number - Ruby Online

Tags: ruby

I have been trying to create a Ruby program that will be running online where a user can guess a number, and it will say higher or lower. I know it will take a random number store in a variable, then run a loop? With conditionals to check?

Im not asking for full code, the basic structure for I can use this to get me going.

Any idea how i would do this? I found info to create a random number like this:

```
x = rand(20)
```

UPDATE: My code I am going to be working with is something like this: http://pastie.org/461976

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say to do something like this:

```
x = rand(20)

loop {
  # get the number from the user somehow, store it in num
  if num == x
    # they got it right
    break
  elsif num > x
    # the guess was too high
  else
    # the guess was too low
  end
}
```

If you're running it online, this structure may not be feasible. You may need to store the guess in the user's session and have a textbox for the guess, and submit it to a controller which would have the above code without the loop construct, and just redirect them to the same page with a message if they didn't get it right.

Comment: Any suggestions to the online part. That is what I mainly confused on. Let me whip up some code that i have so far with that.

Comment: Check out the pastie link I posted in my original question. That should give yo an idea.

Comment: Yeah, the "online" part is just remembering the original number from the session.

Comment: Any idea with the code I have to get an example. I am clueless for htat part

Comment: Something like this: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/classes/CGI/Session.html